# Caching Pages in Rails based on attribute value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I have a PagesController with a show action that currently looks like this:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  caches_page :show

  def show
    @page = Page.get_page(params)
  end

end
```

My Pages model has a **publish_datetime** attribute, and the page isn't available to the public until the **publish_datetime** passes. Is there a way to specify in Ruby that the page should not be cached until the **publish_datetime** has passed?

**Background**: 
Basically, there are people constantly in and out of the page editing the pages prior to their publication date, so that's one reason why I don't want the page to be cached. However, I figured out that I can expire the page on Update, but I'd prefer not to do that. The second reason is that I have a flag called **has_been_published?** that changes the way the page looks. If the page is accidentally cached before the **publish_datetime**, **has_been_published?** never gets called, and the page won't cache with the proper content.

Thanks for any help!
--Mark

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [action caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#action-caching) instead of page caching, so you can use a `before_filter` (or your auth stuff) to determine whether to render the full page or not.